# Break statement not exiting all nested loops within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, break

I am having the understanding that break statement terminates all nested loops.
I have written the following code and it is not working as expected.

```
<script>
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                break;
            }
            document.write(i + '*' + j + '<br>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Actual Output:

```
0*0
0*1
0*2
0*3
0*4
1*0
1*1
1*2
1*3
1*4
2*0
2*1
2*2
2*3
2*4
4*0
4*1
4*2
4*3
4*4
```

As per my understanding, the output should not include `4*0...4*4` because when `i == 3`, the `break` should terminate all nested loops.

### Expected Output:

```
0*0
0*1
0*2
0*3
0*4
1*0
1*1
1*2
1*3
1*4
2*0
2*1
2*2
2*3
2*4
```

Comment: break terminates only the loop within which it is written

Comment: It terminates in the loop it is in, it is not terminating the outerloop. Working as expected. If you moved it before the for (j...., you would get what you were expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify which loop you are breaking from.

```
loop1: for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    loop2: for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (i == 3) {
            break loop1;
        }
        document.write(i + '*' + j + '<br>');
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Answer (score 0):

No, break only breaks the current loop, not all of them. You can use a boolean variable to break out of the enclosing loop as well.

Example:

```
<script>
    let break = false
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                break = true;
                break;
            }
            document.write(i + '*' + j + '<br>');
        }
        if(break) break
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the only innermost loop is escaped but you can achieve the behaviour you are expecting by a self enclosing function and a return statement.

```js
(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                return;
            }
            document.write(i + '*' + j + '<br>');
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place a break in the first loop?

```
<script>
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 3) break;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      document.write(i + '*' + j + '<br>');
    }
  }
</script>
```